# Storing structured data in a database column?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have been having a debate with a coworker about whether it would be a good idea to store structured data (such as XML or JSON) in a database column instead of creating subtables.  For example, say we need to store information about questions.  The two types of questions are Multiple choice and Rating (rate from 1-10 for example).  I would typically create at structure like the one below:

```
Table                   |   Columns
------------------------------------------------------
Question                | ID, Title, QuestionTypeId
Question_MultipleChoice | QuestionId, Choice
Question_Rating         | QuestionId, Min, Max
QuestionTypes           | ID, TypeName
```

My co-worker believes it would be better to store information in a single `Question` table with a column for subinfo.  For example:

```
Question
----------------
ID
Title
SubInfo  <-- JSON
```

Because it would make queries simpler and possibly faster by avoiding JOINS.  Are there reasons that this type of database structure should be avoided?  It seems like if you need to query based on the data in the `SubInfo` column this would be a bad idea, but if that is not needed, is this a reasonable database structure?

Comment: Just to add some gasoline... what about nested tables? http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/NESTED_TABLE  The real answer in my opinion is if the data in the sub table will ever need to be summarized or queried within the database or growth/change of requirements is a possibility, separate tables/columns makes more sense.  If however, you confident of no changes in the short/long run and no analysis will be performed on the structured data, then combining them for performance makes sense.  If you're going for 3rd normal form of database design, structured data is a no-no.

Comment: Interesting!  This is for MySQL so I went ahead and added that tag.  Good info though!

Comment: Under your co-worker's proposed schema, searching for multiple answers could prove tricky I guess. It all rather depends upon the context and use case I'd say.

Comment: Does the last line of my question touch on this at all?  Or are you talking about something different?

Comment: yes it does.  If you need a query based on data in the sub info, it would be a bad idea.  However it is a reasonable structure if it is not needed AND you see no need to change in the long term which could result in a need to query. (but that's just takcing on to the root... it's a bad idea if the data ever needs to be queried.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking very personally, surveys are one case where I think normalizing nothing and storing JSON pretty much *as is* is the better option.

Without it, you're going to end up with all sorts of bizarre use-cases that you'll eventually want to manage down the road. In addition to tidy multiple choice questions of all sorts, you'll also need to manage that "Other" answer in them, condition questions, conditional groups of questions, the list goes on and on. What more, surveys are — like other forms of data — subject to change, and things go from gawdawful to nuclear when they do.

The merit of JSON is that, since surveys are conceptually independent from one another, you've little to no need for referential integrity from one to the next, so you might as well store the entire tree of questions and options as one JSON blob, and worry about formatting it in your app.

The same for each submitted answer, for that matter: take the original blob, mark the relevant answer as selected and so forth within that, and store the resulting JSON *as is*, rather than storing references to the the original questions alongside whatever was answered. This will allow you to readily keep track of what users *actually* answered, as opposed to whatever the current version of the survey says, and do irrespective of how much the survey has diverged since it was originally answered.

If you need to mine the answers later, note that Postgres allows to index JSON using GIST indexes on the whole field, and BTREE indexes on expressions.

Answer (score 1):

JSON, XML are essentially **data types**.

So, if your chosen DB supports that data type and **has** appropriate **set of matching operators** then all is good.

If you plan to stick XML or JSON in a DB and declare it to be a string, then definitely not recommended. String is a string, it is not JSON nor XML.

For example, equality operator for JSON data type knows (or should know) that
`{"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Smith"} = {"lastName": "Smith", "firstName": "John"}`
is **true**.

Equality operator for strings returns **false** for that -- and so on.

Do not expect much from a DB if it can not tell if two things are equal.

Answer (score 0):

We're considering doing both for a similar problem. You could store a blob in the 'Question' table so that you don't have the n+1 issue when trying to retrieve a question with all of its answers, but also keep the 'Answers' table so you can write queries like:

```
SELECT q.*
FROM Questions q
WHERE EXISTS (
           SELECT a.question_id 
           FROM Answers a 
           WHERE 
              a.question_id = q.id AND 
              a.Choice = 'SomeAnswer');
```

If Questions and Answers don't change often, updating both tables on inserts and updates will work fine.

I don't think I would put min/max rating in a separate table though.